# Ionic 3 Ion-row height in internet explorer 11

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m experiencing a problem with the ion-row elements inside ion-grid in internet explorer 11 and ionic 3. They doesn’t have the correct height around the ion-col elements inside ion-grid.

I made a little example so you can reproduce it, please note that the “second row” text in internet explorer 11 is displayed far down in the page, in chrome and other browsers it shows correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vcjcpf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Does anyone experienced this problem? did you find a solution?

Thank you very much
Best regards

Comment: R u developing Web App or Mobile app with ionic-framework ?

Comment: it's a PWA for all platforms, the problem affects only to internet explorer

Comment: But what I am asking is why you want this working in IE 11 at finally you will deploy this on iOS or android right ?

Comment: Runs in browsers too (desktop and mobile)